# Getting an illegalargumentexception when generating random number

Tags: java, android, random

I have this code for generating a random number...

```
public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

        Random rand = new Random();

        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

        return randomNum;
    }
```

I'm using it like so...

```
List<Integer> sounds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public int getSound() {
        return sounds.get(InGameActivity.randInt(0, sounds.size() - 1));
    }
```

I get this error:

```
01-11 00:46:31.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1105): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 00:46:31.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1105): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
01-11 00:46:31.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:175)
01-11 00:46:31.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at com.example.chess.InGameActivity.randInt(InGameActivity.java:2119)
01-11 00:46:31.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at com.example.chess.ChessPiece.getSound(ChessPiece.java:171)
01-11 00:46:31.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at com.example.chess.InGameActivity$MyOnClickListener.onClick(InGameActivity.java:389)
01-11 00:46:31.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
01-11 00:46:31.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
01-11 00:46:31.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-11 00:46:31.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-11 00:46:31.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-11 00:46:31.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-11 00:46:31.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 00:46:31.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-11 00:46:31.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-11 00:46:31.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-11 00:46:31.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: make sure the value of sounds.size() > 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because in your case

```
(max - min) + 1
```

goes less than one

> 01-11 00:46:31.500: E/AndroidRuntime(1105): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0

Comment: actually, it can't be less than zero. it is ZERO