# Method "LiveData<List<SomeType>> getAll" returns 0 when the app is installed the first time

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room

I'm using Room, in my dao I have a method:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Flower")
LiveData<List<Flower>> getAllFlowers();
```

In my activity I'm invoking this method via ViewModel:

```
flowerViewModel.getAllFlowers().observe(ExampleFlowerbedActivity.this, new Observer<List<Flower>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(List<Flower> flowers) {
                         ...
                         int current_color = getRandom(flowers);
                         ...
                    }
                });
```

Inside I'm calling method getRandom():

```
public Integer getRandom(List<Flower> flowers){
                        Flower random = randomFlower(flowers); // here I get an error
                        addedToLayoutFlowers.add(random);
                        List<Integer> random_color = random.getColors_ids();
                        return randomColor(random_color);
                    }
```

Method randomFlower looks like:

```
public Flower randomFlower(List<Flower> list){
    rand = new Random();
    return list.get(rand.nextInt(list.size()));
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
```

I checked the List value that I get from database and it's 0 only when I install app and visit this activity in the first time. When I close the error and open app again everything works perfect.
What can be the problem? Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**
I'm adding flowers right in the database class:

```
@Database(entities = {Flower.class}, version = 2)
@TypeConverters(TypeConverter.class)
public abstract class FlowerDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

private static FlowerDatabase instance2;

public abstract FlowerDao flowerDao();

public static synchronized FlowerDatabase getInstance1(Context context) {
    if (instance2 == null) {
        instance2 = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                FlowerDatabase.class, "flower_database")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .addCallback(room1Callback)
                .build();
    }
    return instance2;
}

private static RoomDatabase.Callback room1Callback = new RoomDatabase.Callback(){
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onCreate(db);
        new Populate1DBAsyncTask(instance2).execute();
    }
};

private static class Populate1DBAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private FlowerDao flowerDao;

    private Populate1DBAsyncTask(FlowerDatabase db){
        flowerDao = db.flowerDao();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    flowerDao.insertFlower(new Flower(....)); // HERE

    ));
        return null;
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Update your post to explain how Flowers are added to the database and why you expect there to be some when the app is first opened after installation.

Comment: I updated my post. Could you please look through it again?

Comment: The argument of `rand.nextInt()` must be positive, otherwise an exception is thrown. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059029/getting-an-illegalargumentexception-when-generating-random-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you have posted, it appears you have a race condition.  Room does not create the database until the first request to perform an operation in the database.  I presume that is your call to `getAllFlowers()`.  Only after that call will the database be created and callback `onCreate()` executed.  Because the population of the database is triggered by `onCreate()` and runs as a background task, it does not complete before your main thread code runs. `getAllFlowers()` returns the empty list of Flowers, which causes the exception.

You need to rework your code to ensure the adding of Flowers is complete before the database is queried.  Or consider using a [prepopulated database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate).